# How to start an activity from non-running android app using BroadcastReciver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog, alarmmanager

I have created an alarm app using `AlarmManager` and `BroadcastReciever`. I want to open an `alertDialog` when an alarm starts ringing.

Here is my `BroadcastReciver` class's code:

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Intent i = new Intent(context, AlertDialogActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
                Log.d("MyTime","OnReceived called");
        }

}
```

Code for `AlertDialogActivity`:

```
public class AlertDialogActivity extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        public void showDialog(Context context, final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm_running, null);
        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(v)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create();

        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

    });
        dialog.show();
}
```

When the app is being running during the alarm ringing, the dialog is displayed successfully. However when the app is not running and alarm gets fired, the `onReciver()` method calls successfully,, however the `dialog` is not displayed.

**In Simple words** the `AlertDialogActivity` does not getting called from `onRecieve()` when the app is closed.

**NOTE:** I am forced to use `AlertDialog` instead of Notifications etc.

What should I do to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: "I am forced to use AlertDialog instead of Notifications etc." -- no, you are forced to use `Notification`, particularly on Android 10 and higher. You cannot start activities from the background anymore.

Comment: But without using activity I am getting the following exception:

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: for resolving this I used activity

Comment: @CommonsWare....

Comment: That error has nothing to do with raising a `Notification`. You cannot start an activity from the background on Android 10+. So, please raise a `Notification`. For your `Theme.AppCompat` problem, please ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve], including the code that generated the crash and the complete stack trace of the crash itself.

Comment: @CommonsWare I used Notifications & now I am able to open my dialog on Notification click. However can I display the dialog as soon as Notification appears(without clicking on it)?

Comment: You can't. The point behind the Android 10 change is to prevent that sort of bad behavior. If you set the `Notification` to be high-priority, it should show up in a "heads-up" form, where a popup form of the `Notification` will appear on-screen briefly.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your response... if your answer is "NO" then how the Android built in Alarm App works?... it shows a notification just before the alarm time and immediately starts an activity, with buttons, where I can stop or snooze alarm

Comment: A manufacturer-supplied app is not necessarily subject to the same limits as a third-party app.